# Random distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random

Have no ideas how to start. Any thoughts?

Ivan Nikiforovich invests his savings in a mutual investment fund. The mutual fund yield is a random variable uniformly distributed over the interval [-10,20]% per annum. Until his retirement, Ivan Nikiforovich has 10 more years left. What is the probability of his savings during this time to grow at least twice?

Comment: This would be equivalent to the probability of $x_1x_2\cdots x_{10}>2$ where $x_i\in [0.9,1.2]$. I do not know how to solve this though

Comment: @GarethMa why? the interval is from -10 to 20.

Comment: percentage? -10%=0.9, +20%=1.2

Comment: Logarithms will turn this product of random variables into a sum of (nonuniform) random variables over the interval.

Comment: @GregMartin and what's next, you know?

Comment: Each year this guy's saving can either grow or shrink. If you only care about grow/shrink with respect to the previous year (an assumption not stated), then the answer is $1 - {10 \choose 0} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{10} - {10 \choose 1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^9 \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: @Ben10 how did you get this answer?

Comment: @Bully If you have no questions anymore, accept the answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to calculate the average growth rate which lead to the double of the investment after 10 years. The equation is $(1+x)^{10}=2\Rightarrow x=2^{\frac1{10}}-1=0.0717734625362931$. With an mutual fund yield of at least $7.17735\%$  we can ensure that investment is at least twice after 10 years.

Next we have to calculate the probability that the mutual fund yield is greater than $7.17735\%$. Here we use the uniform distribution. $$P(X\geq 7.17735\%)=1-P(X\leq 7.17735\%)=1-\frac{0.0717735-(-0.1)}{0.2-(-0.1)}=0.4274217$$

---

Same approach with a slightly different perspective. We can just re-arrange the inequality. Basically the asked probability is $$P\left(\left(1+X \right)^{10}\geq 2\right),$$

where $X\sim U(-0.1,0.2)$

After some transformations we get

$$P\left(X \geq 2^{\frac1{10}}-1\right)$$

Thus Ivan Nikiforovich has a probability of $\color{blue}{42.74\%}$  that his savings grow at least twice in ten years.

Comment: if it has to occur 10 times in a row, that means $0.42^{10}$?

Comment: i suppose this task should be solved with CLT

Comment: Yes. But use as many digital places as possible.

Comment: For CLT you need at least $30$ i.i.d random variables (thumb rule).

Comment: 0.4274217 ** 10 = 0.00020350059021729435 that's not enough, too small probability.

Comment: Why do you think it is too small?

Comment: I suppose, the probability should be greater

Comment: But what can you do if it´s not?

Comment: @Bully II´ve made an update. Yes, it is approximately $42.74\%$